# Definition of Ord for tuples

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to find / work out what definitions of `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` are for tuples. Looking at...

```
(-1, 3) <= (1, 2)  -- True
( 2, 3) <= (1, 2)  -- False
```

... looks like `<=` *could* just be defined using `<=` on the first element of each tuple. However, in this example when first elements are equal...

```
( 1, 3) <= (1, 2)  -- False
```

... means it can't just be `<=` on the first element of each tuple, as it would have been `True`.

What's going on? What is the definition of `<=` and co on tuples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order is [*lexicographic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). It compares the elements from left to right, and the order is defined by the first elements which aren't equal:

```
Prelude> (1, 2) < (1, 3)
True
Prelude> (1, 2) < (1, 1)
False
Prelude> (2, 2) < (1, 1)
False
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an online reference somewhere that says this? (So I have a better chance of finding answers to similar questions in future without asking here...)

Comment: @MichalCharemza You can check out [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out), where it states that this is so for lists, and then discusses the differences between lists an tuples. That's my best reference for this (admittedly, not the greatest).

Comment: @MichalCharemza If you want a language-lawyer level reference, check the Haskell Report. It mandates that tuples work as if they where defined by `data (a,b) = (a,b) deriving (...,Ord)` and the ["deriving" mechanism](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18300011.1) mandates lexicographic ordering.

Comment: add order can be changed with the `Down` from the `Data.Ord`